# Requesting memory before launching an AsyncTask and how manage it

Tags: android, memory-management, android-asynctask

i have an huge app with a lot of nested activity that contains fragments with a lot of informations.

**APP Logic**:

- Activity with list of projects
- Click a Project Name start another activity with tabbed fragments
- One of this Fragments contain the List of Feeds
- Click a Feed start another Activity with tabbed Fragments with all Feed informations (Here i create a PDF report with Feed informations)

I try to generate a PDF report and sometimes i get a crash with this error:

```
A/art: art/runtime/gc/collector/mark_sweep.cc:413] Tried to mark 0xebadde09 not contained by any spaces
       art/runtime/utils.cc:184] 12c00000-12ca5000 rw-p 00000000 00:01 33268                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main
```

and a lot of lines over...
The last message before error is:

```
compiler allocated 5MB to compile java.io.File ...
```

It seems like a memory problem.

First time i try to put an async task that generate the PDF report but some times i get the same error, so now i call the thread from another activity that don't contain the all datas contained in the last activity related to Project selected.
The problem is that i see from Android Profiler that memory usage is lower that first approach (launch async task from Activity that contain fragments with all project informations) but not so better.

There is something that can i do for avoid that?
Something like reserve memory for task or intercept the crash and notify user about that (maybe say to him clear your app stack before proceed).
The best way to manage that situations in less words:

Here the AsyncTask that call method that generate report

```
 private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<Void, String, File> {

        private File pdfFile;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected File doInBackground(Void... params) {
            pdfGenerator = new PdfGenerator(currentObject, "Project", getApplicationContext());
            try {
                pdfFile = pdfGenerator.createPdf();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something goes wrong with generated file, please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something goes wrong with generated file, please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something goes wrong with generated file, please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            return pdfFile;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(File pdfFile) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            viewPdf(pdfFile);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ReportPdfActivity.this,
                    "Making PDF report...",
                    "Please wait for the PDF report");
        }
    }
```

PS: I try to `finish()` the last `Activity` before call ActivityReport that manage report generation and the memory from ~60MB go down to ~50MB but the problem is that all Activities are related by Project so if i destroy the activity that call "generate report" i broke the logic chain that connect all activities among them, so before re-write the activity logic connection and `finish()` all of them when call another `Activity` with Fragment i want to know the best solution for that.

Thanks

**EDIT Better explanation of app structure**

This App take data from Odoo 11 web app ERP.
We used a framework for that and it have a huge thinks.

If the user is logged the first Activity contain in the main view a list of all projects (and a navigation Drawer for manage other fragments like settins, profile and other stuff)

From Projects Fragment by onClickListner it's open another Activity (with 
tabbed view fragments) that show different type of data related to this Project, like IssueFragment, TaskFragment, FeedFragment.
All of this fragments showed by tabbed top menu contain a list of related arguments (issue, task etc etc).
Every onClick element call a Simple Activity that show details to related item... BUT the Feed list open another Activity with (again) a tabbed top menu for navigate different fragments (because feed can have questions, issues, tasks, signatures etc etc)....

So the final situation is that

-- Activity with navigation drawer and related Fragments

---- (Project Fragment onClick) Activity with tabbed fragments ([Android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral))

------ (FeedFragment onClick) Activity with Feed details distribuited on different Fragments

**The parenthesis (... onClick) means onClick in the last Activity/Fragment**

**EDIT 2**
Changed AsyncTask with Thread

PDFGenerator.java

```
   public PdfGenerator(Integer currentObject, String objectType, Context context, Handler handler) {
        this.currentObject = currentObject;
        this.objectType = objectType;
        this.context = context;
        this.mHandler = handler;

       //OTHER STUFFS....

    }

   /**
     * Update UI according to the current state of PDF Creation
     */
    private synchronized void showDialogHandler() {
        // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
        mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.SHOW_DIALOG, 1).sendToTarget();
    }

    private synchronized void dismissDialogHandler() {
        // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
        mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.SHOW_DIALOG, 1).sendToTarget();
    }

    public synchronized void startPdfCreation() {

        Log.d(TAG, "Start PDF CREATION ");

        simplePdfThread = null;
        snaggingPdfThread = null;

        // Start the thread to connect with the given device
        simplePdfThread = new PdfSimpleThread();
        simplePdfThread.start();
        // show dialog
        showDialogHandler();
    }

    public synchronized void startPdfSnaggingCreation() {

        Log.d(TAG, "Start PDF SNAGGING CREATION ");

        snaggingPdfThread = null;
        simplePdfThread = null;

        // Start the thread to connect with the given device
        snaggingPdfThread = new PdfSnaggingThread();
        snaggingPdfThread.start();
        // show dialog
        showDialogHandler();
    }

    private class PdfSimpleThread extends Thread {
        File pdf;

        public PdfSimpleThread() {
            pdf = null;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                pdf = createPdf();
                mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.PDF_DONE, pdf).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException | DocumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private class PdfSnaggingThread extends Thread {
        File pdf;

        public PdfSnaggingThread() {
            pdf = null;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                pdf = createSnaggingListPdf();
                mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.PDF_DONE, pdf).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException | DocumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private File createPdf() throws IOException, DocumentException {
    //ALL THE STUFF HERE.... (it's over than 100 code lines)
    }

    private File createSnaggingListPdf() //...... it's same
```

And the Handler from Caller Activity:

```
@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case Constants.PDF_MESSAGE:
                Toast.makeText(ActivityFeedDetails.this, "Generating PDF...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case Constants.SHOW_DIALOG:
                int sentInt = (int) msg.obj;
                if (sentInt == 1){
                    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ActivityFeedDetails.this,
                            "Making PDF report...",
                            "Please wait for the PDF report");
                } else {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                break;

            case Constants.PDF_DONE:
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                pdfGenerator = null;
                pdfFile = (File) msg.obj;
                viewPdf(pdfFile);
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

This get a better performance....and generate the PDF report if i close the app or activity too (The AsyncTask don't do that).
And i improve the methods that generate pdf because i see that i pre-load all `List<ODataRow>` before start creating (and now i call them only when i need so i can clear the other with `.clear();`)...
`ODataRow` it's a class that implements `Serializable`

Comment: Usually asking for more memory is not the solution - asking for more memory is a work-around for an underlying structural issue which sounds like that's the issue for you - your architecture sounds quite weird. Is this app on Google Play Store or do you have any screenshots of it, that you could show us?
You shouldn't really have to kill `Activities` on your own - yes `finish()` will eventually destroy the `Activity`, but in the end Android will control this for you.
What I'm getting at: there's an underlying issue that you should look into first.

Comment: @Darwind thanks for reply.
No the app isn't on Play Store because it's created for personal use in our company!
But if you can say to me witch screenshoot you need i can do something!

First of all i see that for heavy job it's not a good idea to use AsyncTask, so i moved the logic like Bluetooth Connection example from Android Developer by using Threads and Handler

Comment: `AsyncTask` is not necessarily a bad idea - it can do the heavy lifting the same a `Thread` as it is just a `Thread` in the end. If you want to create a long-running task that needs to be able to run in the background while the user navigates around in the app, you could use an `IntentService` for instance that runs in the background and doesn't have to be related to a specific `Activity` for instance.
I'm not sure which screenshots I'd like to see - I just wanted to figure out how your hierarchy were, since it sounded like everything was tightly coupled to each other.

Comment: Oh, and I don't believe a Bluetooth connection is not a "heavy job" in any way - how did you get to that conclusion? I'm working on an app with BLE connection and it doesn't add much to the memory footprint when we're using the BLE.

Comment: Sorry, i say bluetooth by example of Threadings, not like heavy duty :D
My university partner say to me that AsyncTask are related to Activities that call it, and it's better to use Thread with Handler for this kind of job (like generate a pdf).
I try to explain better the App Activity Fragments connections to the main question!

Comment: Ok, got it :-)
Google actually has examples with using `AsyncTask`s inside `ViewModel`s that yes are related to `Fragment`s or `Activity`s, but if the work you're doing is closely related to an `Activity` or a `Fragment` then `AsyncTask` can do the work nicely for you as well.

Comment: Edit the main post... i hope that is little bit clear the explanation :) ....
Anyway nope, the task it's unrelated to Activity.... i can call the Thread and close the App and wait for the generated report, because i pass to the class that generate report the "id" of element where take information from DB...

Comment: Great, I'll have a read - related to the long running task I would use a `Service` instead then that's being run as a foreground service with a `Thread` inside. Don't use a `Thread` directly.

Comment: From your current question I'm not able to recommend you to do something specific as it's too broad to figure out what the culprit is, but my best guess is there's an issue with the `PdfGenerator` or how you use it. Your app doesn't sound too complex to me and remember that only one `Activity` is visible so that's what'll use memory. If Android thinks the other `Activities` in your app is spending too much memory it'll kick them out of memory.

Comment: @Darwind i update the post with new code.... can i have your judgment? :D 
Anyway the performance are better know and don't crash...or not again :D

Many Thanks

Comment: Great that you've seemed to solve the issue, but it's a bit weird why it would have anything to do with your `AsyncTask`. Unless it was leaking the `Activity` it was created in for instance I can't think of any reasons why it wouldn't be ok to use an `AsyncTask` for heavy duty. Yes there might be an overhead of using an `AsyncTask` probably, because there's probably more logic in it than a `Thread`, but I wouldn't say that's the culprit. But great you solved it anyways ;-)

Comment: I'm not pretty sure about that...but hope that work!
Even because if the app crash...the Thread keep working and generate Pdf anyway (i think).
Thanks for the comparison!